# Cassandra dies with Out of memory: Kill process or sacrifice child

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We have a 6 node cluster, running:

- Cassandra 3.11.0.1900
- DSE 5.1.5
- Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

One of the nodes dies with the following message in syslog:

> [1770962.274743] Out of memory: Kill process 49468 (java) score 893 or
>   sacrifice child [1770962.299330] Killed process 49468 (java)
>   total-vm:1156754248kB, anon-rss:46906424kB, file-rss:176871432kB

Swap is disabled on the node, and `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` is set to 0. Note that this happens when `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` is set to 1 also.

Unfortunately, there are no related error messages in the Cassandra `system.log` (we are logging at level debug).

Any ideas as to what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Based on the error in "syslog" its related to your VM and nothing to do with Cassandra. Check with your system team on the memory management of this server. They can move it to a better hardware

Comment: Unfortunately, I have two other nodes with the same VM settings and versions and those don't crash with this error.

Comment: As the VM provisioning goes, no one ever knows which hardware is backing it. Having said that, Check the access pattern whether this node is becoming hot spot.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this was unanswered so figured it deserved to be answered. This isn't a DSE/Cassandra problem as such rather it might mean you simply dont have enough memory for whats running on the host. When the OOM killer reaps a process generally it will kill the largest one. Typically with DSE in situations like this it might mean you have perhaps set the heap (Xmx) in your `jvm.options` file too high. This is just one of a number of things it might be mind you.

There are other nuances as to why the OOM killer will reap a process, but this can get quite involved and without knowing your system setup and what other processes are running its hard to tell.

You won't see any messages in the DSE/Cassandra logs though, this is quite normal because the process is terminated forcefully by the oom killer (like a `kill -9`) therefore the logs will just stop.